# std::get conflict when switching to Boost 1.64

Tags: c++, boost

I am using gcc 6.2 (with -std=c++14). I have a big project that builds against Boost 1.62 with no problem. When I switch to Boost 1.64, I get this error:

```
.../include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:133:11: error: ‘template<long unsigned int Idx, class T, long unsigned int N> con 
    st T& std::get(const boost::array<T, N>&)’ conflicts with a previous declaration 
      using ::get; 
              ^~~ 

...include//boost/array.hpp:429:13: note: previous declaration ‘template<long unsigned int Idx, class T, long unsigned int N> con 
    st T& boost::get(const boost::array<T, N>&)’ 
       const T &get(const boost::array<T,N> &arr) BOOST_NOEXCEPT { 
                ^~~
```

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the problem with a simple example (unsure of what the problem might be, I made an empty main() that includes `property_map.hpp` and `array.hpp` and that builds fine), so I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction :).

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace ...` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @user0042 The only time I do that is `using namespace boost::accumulators;` and it's inside one of my own namespaces.

Comment: Do you have a function named "get" somewhere in your code?

Comment: @tambre I do have a couple of `get(...)` functions, but they are all member functions - nothing in the `global`, `std`, or `boost` namespace.

Comment: Please just reduce the code (removing code) until the error disappears. Ultimately I think it's gonna be down to including several headers with specific defines (like `BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_ARRAY`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to look for statements importing a single function:

```
using std::get;
```

Instead of just importing a whole namespace which contains get():

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Ah, there was a 'using ::testing::get;' that I didn't find when I grepped for "using namespace". Google Mock must be aliasing that to `std::get` or something like that (though I couldn't find it...). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because boost introduces that template function in [array.hpp vesion 1.64](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/array/reference.html#header.boost.array_hpp), that was not there in [array.hpp vesion 1.62](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/array/reference.html#header.boost.array_hpp)
(That's why you did not get this compiler error before)

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t Idx> 
    T boost::get(const array<T, N>&);
```

Anyway, the problem is because you are mixing namespace (`std` with `boost`) somewhere in your code. See [std::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get)

Get rid of `using namespace std;` and `using namespace boost;` in headers.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. It claims two separate reasons. I know the first is not the problem (I checked). I know you want to explain that something changed between 1.62-64 but that much was pretty much a given.

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that is an completely different diagnostic. You can play with things yourself http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a4a28683c17906 - I haven't been able to repro it